# Windows 10 - Using Labellmg for object detection - Installing PyQt

Tags: python, qt, visual-studio-2010, pyqt, deep-learning

A beginner here.I have been trying to get Labellmg work using the following source on Github:

https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

I was confused as to if I could just download the .exe file found in 'Download prebuilt binaries' or if I have to build it from source. So, I went with building it from source anyway:

Here are the steps I followed: (I have python 3.5 and lxml already installed)

1. Installed Visual Studio 2010 from here:
   http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2010-Ultimate/3000-2383_4-75450998.html
2. Downloaded SIP source code (version 4.19.5) from here:
   https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download
3. Downloaded PyQt4 source code (version 4.12.1) from here:
   https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download
4. Downloaded and Installed Qt
   (qt-opensource-windows-x86-vs2010-4.8.6.exe)

Staying in one Command Prompt and in the sip-4.19.5 directory, I entered the following commands:

1. python configure.py
2. "C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qtvars.bat"
3. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
   10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
4. nmake

The first three steps are successful but when I execute the nmake command, I get the following error:

[image]

I am probably doing something really silly. Kindly, please help me out! I have been stuck with this problem for more than 8 hours straight now.

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to go through all this hassle when there are pre-built binaries available.